# updating $vm0 doesn't update data instantly

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a VueJS- HTML file like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="name in names" v-text="name"></li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" id="input" v-model="newName" />
    <button @click="addName">Add Name</button>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"</script>

  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#root',
      data: {
        newName: '',
        names: ['Joe', 'Mary', 'Jane']
       },
      methods: {
        addName() {
          this.names.push(this.newName);
          this.newName = '';
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Whenever I do this in console

```
$vm0.names[0] = 'Gurung'
```

It doesn't update the first name instantly but I have to add a new name to get it updated. Another thing is this variable works only when I click on Root in the Vue Extension. One guess of mine was that $vm0 was just used by extension but why does doing manipulations with it changes it in DOM too (not instantly as I told earlier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect the following
> changes to an array:
>
> When you directly set an item with the index, e.g.
> `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`. When you modify the length of the
> array, e.g. `vm.items.length = newLength`.

[Reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)

`$vm0.$set($vm0.names, 0, 'Grung');`

Comment: But I want the reason why wouldn't my solution worked and why I have to add a new name to make it work?

Comment: The reason that Vue can not detect direct setting an item with index. Thus it does not update a DOM.

Comment: Has it helped? :)